# How can I find the Google Apps Owner / Admin via Google APIs?

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

Is there an API call that will tell me the Default Admin / Owner of a Google Apps Enterprise account?

I will be making the API calls from a non-admin user account on the same enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non admins do not have access to determine who the admins are. At the minimum, they'll need to be a delegated admin with read-only user access to the APIs privileges assigned.

Assuming they have those rights they can call users.list() to get a list of all users. Each user includes the attributes isAdmin and isDelegatedAdmin that can be used to determine Super Admins (isAdmin) and Delegated Admins.